# Why Python can't use [[]*m]*n to repeat lists into one list?

Tags: python, list, duplicates, repeat

I find when repeating an element to a list, people use `[elem] * n`. But when repeating a list to a list, people use `[[list] for _ in range(n)]`, instead of `[[list]] * n`. I see comments saying that the latter will cause a problem due to "mutable" feature of a list, and I can see the result of the problem in my code. Can anybody explain what problem this method will cause, and what might be the consequence?

Comment: [The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/240205/15497888) goes through why this happens in detail. [The question itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/240178/15497888) outlines one of the consequences of having multiple references to the same list.

Comment: The top answer to the duplicate clearly explains the problem. It's not just that it's mutable, it's that list multiplication duplicates the references to the contents without copying them, so `[[0]] * 5` produces a `list` of five elements, all of which refer to the *same* `[0]` `list`.